# What is the best way to create a moving window in 2D array ond order pixels

Tags: python, numpy

I'm very new to Python, and need do to a bit of tricky 2D array manipulation with it. I'm not sure of the best way to go about it.

Basically, I start with an array of values between 0 and 1.

I need to have a moving 2x2 window to apply to the 2D array, (edit: where the array is a 2D image; ie say 200x200 pixels or so) and within each 2x2 window, assign values 1-4, inversely, according to the array value weights (ie, the minimum cell in the 2x2 becomes 4, then the next minimum becomes 3, etc.)

I can see how to extract my 2x2 windows by a nested loop; is that the best way?

More tricky is how to go about the ordering assignment.

I thought to use numpy.where (subarray.min) iteratively on my window subarrays, but I can't see how to GET at the returned location where returns! I'm not sure that there isn't a better way to go about this.

Advice? Pointers to how to do complicated, messy, array manipulations with NumPy?

Comment: Do your 2x2 windows overlap? or are they packed tight "side-by-side"? or  are they randomly located?

Comment: They do not overlap; they are 'packed tight, side by side' the input array is divisible by two.  Not random; continuous (is how I need to place the window).

Comment: (for example - my current input array is 268 x 270)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're starting with an array like this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(20).reshape((10,-1))

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19]])
```

What you are looking for is `reshape` and `argsort`, I think.

Using the `reshape` member function you can change the shape without changing the sequence:

```
In [4]: a.reshape((-1,4))
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Reshape takes a tuple. I like to think of that as (number of rows, number or columns). In this case, (-1,4) means: use 4 columns (so each row has four numbers in it), and calculate the amount of rows from the amount of data.

Using `argsort` you can get the array that you want.

```
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: d = np.random.random((10, 2)).reshape((-1,4))

In [4]: d
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.65945195,  0.1907593 ,  0.1630845 ,  0.76949532],
       [ 0.90823488,  0.71518689,  0.38422877,  0.77824007],
       [ 0.31453967,  0.76592537,  0.5871099 ,  0.09306465],
       [ 0.38251335,  0.97461878,  0.97562622,  0.87532202],
       [ 0.12358359,  0.20323007,  0.397975  ,  0.615806  ]])


In [7]: e = np.array([4-np.argsort(r) for r in d])

In [8]: e
Out[8]: 
array([[2, 3, 4, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 4],
       [1, 4, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 3, 2],
       [4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

As you can see, each row now has the required indices. Let's go over what line 7 does from the inside out:

- `for r in d`: iterate over all rows in d.
- `4 - np.argsort(r)`: argsort would create indices in the rang 0-3. So we substract it from 4 to get to a inverse 4-1 range. In numpy arrays, operations are done to each element, so `4 - np.array([2, 1, 0, 3])` acts like `np.array([4,4,4,4]) - np.array([2, 1, 0, 3])`.
- `[]`: the previous lines wrapped between square brackets make it a list comprehension, which is like a very fast and compact for-loop returning a list.
- `np.array`: The list of arrays is combined into one big array.

Then using another reshape, you bring the data back into its original shape

```
In [9]: e.reshape((-1,2))
Out[9]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

**Edit**:

Based on your comment, you can do the following. Say you have a 2D matrix:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(100).reshape((-1,10))

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

You can select a 2x2 submatrix like this:

```
In [4]: a[3:5, 0:2]
Out[4]: 
array([[30, 31],
       [40, 41]])
```

The patteren here is `a[row:row+2, column:column+2]`. Using the `reshape` and `argsort` techniques shown above you can create the new values.

```
In [5]: p = a[3:5, 0:2]

In [6]: e = 4-np.argsort(p.reshape((1,4))).reshape((2,2))

In [7]: e
Out[7]: 
array([[4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

You can then place this result in the original array or in a copy:

```
In [12]: a[3:5, 0:2] = e

In [13]: a
Out[13]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [ 4,  3, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [ 2,  1, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

Note that both the width and height of the image need to be even for a 2x2 submatrix to work as intended...

Comment: Roland - Ok I *think* I get it!  Will work from your example and see how I do.  Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: I would if I could figure out how to extend your example to my input array with the methods you illustrate, but I'm not quite getting there, ie, my 'array' is a 2D image, actually, and I want to preserve the order of that image. I somehow need to subset - or consider a subset - of the array in 2D, and move that subset around the image.

Comment: @passiflora You might want to add that to your question. It makes it a lot clearer. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you, Roland;  will try to edit my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help [refer to [here](http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268)]

Invocation:

```
x = np.arange(36).reshape((6, 6))
print(x)
b = sliding_window(x, (2, 3), None, False) 
print(b)
```